# XGBoost: When categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter `enable_categorical` must be set to `True`

Tags: python, xgboost

I have a dataframe `data` whose columns are exclusively made by NUMERICAL variable (integers and floats) and a pandas series `labels` whose elements are strings (either `"Exercise"` or `"Rest`) corresponding to the labels of the rows of `data`. I want to train an XGBoost classifier, but when I use the call:

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data, label=labels)
```

I get the error "When categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter `enable_categorical` must be set to `True`" and then the error message prints a list of all the column names of `data` (which, I repeat, contain only numerical variables). To me it seems like the names of the columns are interpreted as categorical variables. How can I fix this?
Thanks :)